# How do I SSH into an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I new client gave me their root AWS site login credentials. I can see the EC2 instance IP address. Are the SSH credentials available in the AWS web portal? Or do I have to create new credentials?

Comment: check for something like "Key pair assigned at launch" at the details tab of EC2 instance. If there is one, then the credentials are already have been created and you will need the private key to ssh into the ec2

Answer (score 2):

SSH private keys generated by AWS are generated once. When you create a new SSH key, you have to save the generated .pem file (private key file) onto your local system.

If they gave you root credentials to the AWS console but not the server credentials, you will have to ask for them first.

You need these 3 things in order to connect through SSH

- server IP
- SSH username
- SSH key / password

Once you have that, you can run this command on your terminal

if you use username / password

`ssh <ssh-username>@<server-ip>`

if you use username / private key

`ssh -i path/to/key.pem <ssh-username>@<server-ip>`

Answer (score 0):

The SSH private key credentials are private. AWS doesn't keep a copy of them. You'll need to create new ones.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-ec2reset.html